# How to write each row of a text file into a CSV row

Tags: perl, csv

I am new to perl and I am trying to take a file (it's actually an `.idx` file) that is formatted like this

```
 Monday       Foo Name             43212    
 Tuesday      Name Foo Foo         43252
 Tuesday      Name                 50322 
 Wednesday    Foo Name             53221
 Thursday     Foo Bar Foo Name     24353
```

and I want to output it as a csv file. The file should look exactly like this, except in CSV format so that Excel can read it. Also, I only want the rows that are on Tuesday to be included so that the CSV file will look like

```
 Tuesday      Name Foo Foo     43252
 Tuesday      Name             50322
```

In Excel. I also have several `idx` files in the format `formYYYY_Q.idx` where `YYYY` refers to the year and `Q` refers to the quarter.  I would like to loop over all the `.idx` files I have and create one large CSV file with only rows in each `.idx` file with `Tuesday` at the beginning.  The code I have so far is

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use warnings;
 use strict;
 use Text::CSV;

 my $csvfile= Text::CSV->new({binary=>1,auto_diag=>1});
 $csvfile->column_names("Day","Name","Number");

 my @datalines;
 my $idxfile="form1994_1.idx";

 open(INFILE, "< $idxfile") or die $!;
 open(my $outfile, "> Master.csv") or die $!;

 while(<INFILE>){

      if(/^Tuesday/){

            chomp($_);
            push(@nsarlines, $_);

     }

 }
```

When I replace the open command with `open(OUTFILE, "> Master.txt") or die $!;` and include this in the last line of code outside the while loop:

```
 print OUTFILE map {"$_ \n"} @nsarlines;
```

the Master.txt file looks looks like I want it to

```
 Tuesday      Name Foo Foo     43252
 Tuesday      Name             50322
```

However, if I use the open command as written above do something like this outside the while loop:

```
 $csvfile-> print($outfile, \@test);
```

I get a CSV file with the entire `$_` string, which is one row of the `.idx` file in each cell of the Master.csv file. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make perl make each `.idx` row a CSV row WIHTOUT manually inserting commas into `$_` (not an elegant or desirable option).

The second thing I need to do is I have files `formYYY_Q.idx` all in the same directory and I would like to automatically go through each one, pull out the rows that start with Tuesday and add those to the Master.csv file (or rather, do all of that and write the Master.csv file once at the end). I think `File::Find` might be able to do this, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you want to insert commas?  csv is an acronym for Comma Separated Values.  You can do it easily with `split /\s+/` and `join ","`.  I'll be honest, I don't see a reason to use a module for writing csv files.  Reading, yes.  Writing, no.

Comment: @avitevet the actual file has `Fooname` variables of differing word lenghts. That is one might be `Company Foofirm` while another might be  `Holding Foofirm Parters`. If I use `split /\s+/` it will put a comma in everywhere there is a space in my data. So I will get `"Tuesday,Holding,Foofirm,Partners,43252"` rather than `"Tuesday,Holding Foofirm Partners,43252"`. And there isn't any regular uniform pattern to how many words make up the company name.

Comment: If you do not want to process your lines, but simply reprint them, you should perhaps just use grep: `grep "^Tuesday" form1994_1.idx`

Comment: I see... but there must be some delimiter, correct?  Otherwise, how will any script know where to properly place the commas?  Could you split on the delimiter?  And I agree, with TLP, if you want to just reprint them you can do this with a single command line: find . -name '*.idx' -type f -exec grep Tuesday '{}' \; > Master.csv

Comment: @avitevet unfortunately there isn't any delimiter aside from "somewhat" consistent spaces between columns. I was hoping the hidden characters were just individual `\t` but they are all `\s` of various lengths. I ended up just "manually" inserting commas into each iteration of the loop and had to tinker with adding spaces to some columns so that all 64,000 lines came out correctly. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use File::Find.  One is you use the `wanted` function to add data about the files to a global list/queue/variable, then process the data after the `find` call.  The other way is to perform all the processing in the `wanted` function.

I personally don't like using globals to pass data out of functions but unfortunately with File::Find that is your option.  Here's an example where they do that: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=217378.  In the example, they use the %size hash to pass data out of the anonymous `wanted` function.  This is probably your best option, you would add the matching filenames to a global list, then iterate through the list, writing data from each file to your CSV.

The other option is to perform your processing in the `wanted` function.  But again this is suboptimal, because you will need to use globals to pass information *into* the `wanted` function about the open CSV file.

Another option, assuming that all your .idx files can be guaranteed to be in the same directory (rather than in the same dir tree) is to use the opendir & readdir functions.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html

```
my $dh;   # directory handle
opendir($dh, $your_dir) || die $!;
my @idxfiles = grep {/\.idx$/} readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

foreach my $idxfile (@idxfiles) {
   open(INFILE, "< $idxfile") or die $!;
   ... the rest of your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combined some of the op's  code and some of avitevet's, and came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

opendir(DIR, ".") or die $!;
my @idxfiles = sort(grep {/\.idx$/} readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

open(OUT, "> Master.csv") or die $!;
foreach my $idx (@idxfiles) {
  open(F, "$idx") or die $!;
  while (<F>) {
    if (m/^Tuesday/) {
      my @fields = split(/\s+/);
      my $day = shift(@fields); # grab the first one
      my $zip = pop(@fields); # grab the last one;
      my $middle = join(" ", @fields); # merge the rest back together
      print OUT "$day,$middle,$zip\n";
    }
  }
  close(F)
}
close(OUT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. My actual file has more than three columns. Could just use `shift` to work through all of the columns until the last one and then join them all at the end?

Comment: In my code, the row is split on spaces/whitespace.  Since you've indicated that the 2nd field can also contain spaces, my code only works if you shift off the first column and then pop off that last column.  If you kept shifting thru the columns, you'd break up the 2nd field field wherever there are spaces in it.  If that's the ONLY field with spaces, you could shift off the first, and pop off columns 3 & beyond, leaving you with the "$middle" shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I applaud the clear description of your problem and your attempted solution!

Given your narrative, including having all of your idx files in one directory, consider the following solution--to be executed in the *.idx-containing directory:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $outfile, '>', 'Master.csv' or die $!;
print $outfile "Day,Name,Number\n";

for my $idxfile (<*.idx>) {
    next unless $idxfile =~ /^form\d{4}_\d\.idx/;
    open my $infile, '<', $idxfile or die $!;

    while (<$infile>) {
        if (/^Tuesday/) {
            my ( $day, $name, $num ) = /(\w+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+)/;
            print $outfile "$day,$name,$num\n";
        }
    }

    close $infile;
}

close $outfile;
```

The header is first written to the Master.csv file.  The `<*.idx>` construct is a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) that generates a list of *.idx files from the current directory.  Next, a regex is used to insure that the filename matches your naming specs.  If only those files you want processed are in the directory, you can delete this line.

The current idx file is opened and processed.  As in your code, a regex is used to check for "Tuesday" at the beginning of the line.  If such a line is encountered, a regex captures the three fields:

```
/(\w+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+)/
   ^   ^  ^    ^   ^
   |   |  |    |   |
   |   |  |    |   + - One+ digits - Number
   |   |  |    + - One+ whitespaces
   |   |  + - One+ any characters (except newline) - Name
   |   + - One+ whitespaces 
   + - One+ 'word' characters - Day
```

These captured fields--with commas separating them--are written to the Master.csv file.  When the current idx file is completely read, it's closed, and the next idx file is processed--if any.  Finally, the Master.csv file is closed.

Hope this helps!